# Как правильно писать в официальном документе?

Tags: орфография

Первый заместитель Министра или Первый заместитель министра?

Answer (score 1):

Название должности должно соответствовать официальному названию.
Первый заместитель министра - это самостоятельная должность, написание не привязывается к тому, как надо писать "министр".

Если проверить по официальным документам возможности нет, то естественное написание - со строчной: ***первый заместитель министра***. Причем и первого слова - тоже. Хотя все равно лучше бы контекст смотреть. Есть еще такое понятие как "условное имя собственное" (ну типа [высокие договаривающиеся] Стороны), это частично оправдывает написание с заглавной первого слова. Но не последнего.

Answer (score 0):

***Ответ справочной службы русского языка***

Согласно орфографическим нормам, с прописной буквы пишутся только названия высших государственных должностей, и то лишь в текстах официальных документах. Такие названия должностей, как **министр, губернатор (и тем более генеральный директор, председатель комиссии, мэр**), пишутся строчными.

Однако написания, принятые в современной официальной документации, зачастую противоречат орфографическим нормам. Такова ситуация и со словом **министр**. Написание этого слова с прописной рекомендовано, например, **«Кратким справочником по оформлению актов Совета Федерации Федерального Собрания Российской Федерации».** Поэтому, если речь идет об официальной документации (как в вопросе, на который Вы ссылаетесь), приходится давать соответствующие рекомендации.

- **Дополнение**

**Редакция портала Грамота.ру**

Трудно что-то добавить к уже сказанному. Документами, в которых уместно написание **заместитель Министра,** Государственная Дума и т. п. написания, противоречащие орфографическим нормам, полагаем, можно считать указы, распоряжения и т. п. документы, издаваемые государственными органами; документы, предназначенные для отправки в государственные органы, а также разного рода канцелярские бумаги, которые «гуляют» между ведомствами. В документах, которые никоим образом не относятся к данным учреждениям (тот же отчет о собрании акционеров), конечно, следует рекомендовать писать по правилам.

Comment: Вопрос-то стоит, ***как писать "первый заместитель"***.